# Which of the 3D point groups exactly are abelian, and why?

Tags: group-theory, geometry

I am trying to understand which symmetry point groups (in 3D) are abelian and which are not, except from the definition how can I see and understand that quickly?

I see that I could compile a list myself somehow but thats not what I am asking for (see below). I am used to Schoenflies notation only, so preferentially use that for any answer, please.

For the sake of progress I will start to compile the list:

Abelian: C$_1$, C$_s$, C$_i$, C$_n$, S$_{2n}$, C$_{nh}$, C$_{2v}$, D$_2$.

Non-Abelian: S$_{2n+1}$, C$_{(2+n)v}$, D$_{(2+n)v}$, D$_{nd}$, T, T$_h$, T$_d$, O, O$_h$, I, I$_h$, C$_{\infty v}$, D$_{\infty h}$.

with $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$.

I think thats all, so maybe its the quickest to learn the abelian ones by heart.

Comment: Is for instance the fact that all irreps are one dimensional an exact condition?

Comment: I found another one: all groups up to order 4 are abelian. That means: C$_1$, C$_s$, C$_i$, C$_{2v}$ and D$_2$ are abelian by that criterion. Then there remain only S$_{2n}$ and C$_{nh}$ to be learned.

Comment: Of which C$_{n}$ (I forgot that in the last comment), and C$_{nh}$  are relatively easy to see be geometrical intuition. Remains S$_{2n}$ as abelian and S$_{2n+1}$ as non-abelian to be memorised.